# How to find the number of lines and different elements in a file and writing them on header, Scala

Tags: scala, file, file-writing

I have something like:

```
object Example_01_IO {

  val s = Source.fromFile("example_01.txt")
  val source = s.getLines()
  val destination = new PrintWriter(new File("des_example_01.txt"))

  var nrVariables: Int = 0
  var nrLines: Int = 0

  // here are the extracted lines from example_01 that fulfills some conditions.
  val linesToWrite: Iterator[String] = ... 

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    //Here is the header that I want to write in a destination file
    destination.write("des_example_01.txt \n")
    destination.write("Nr. of Variables and Lines: " + nrVariables + " " + nrLines + "\n")

    for(line <- linesToWrite) {
      println(line)
      destination.write(line)
      destination.write("\n")
      nrLines += 1
    }

    s.close()
    destination.close()

  }
```

I need to have the values for `nrVariables` and `nrLines` to write in the header of the destination file (e.g., in the second row). Is there a possibility to calculate these two values before starting to write the other lines?

Any help or reference is really welcomed. Thank you.

Comment: Looks like a homework). You should either save linesToWrite into a List (just call toList on the source) so you can reuse it or read the file twice.

Comment: @vitalii , homework? I have finished the univ. for 10 years now. I have saved them in a List and I have tried so many tricks. When I read the file twice I get either the number of Lines and Variables, or the Lines, but not both. And I cannot know what makes this to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Source.fromFile can not be reused, the one below works fine:

```
package example

import java.io.PrintWriter
import scala.io.Source
import java.io.File

object Example_01_IO {

  def s = Source.fromFile("/tmp/example_01.txt") // notice def everywhere, looks like Source.fromFile could not be reused :(
  def source = s.getLines() 
  val destination = new PrintWriter(new File("/tmp/des_example_01.txt"))

  var nrVariables: Int = 0
  var nrLines: Int = 0

  // here are the extracted lines from example_01 that fulfills some conditions.
  def linesToWrite: Iterator[String] = source.filter { s => s.contains("a") } 

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    linesToWrite.foreach { s =>  
      nrLines += 1
      if (s contains "variable") {
        nrVariables += 1
      }
    }


    //Here is the header that I want to write in a destination file
    destination.write("des_example_01.txt \n")
    destination.write("Nr. of Variables and Lines: " + nrVariables + " " + nrLines + "\n")

    for(line <- linesToWrite) {
      println(line)
      destination.write(line)
      destination.write("\n")
      /*nrLines += 1*/
    }

    s.close()
    destination.close()

  }
  }
```

Comment: oh, really? I am going around with this for 2 days now :(. I didn't know that `Source.fromFile can not be reused`. (Before) I tried to change only the `val linesToWrite =...` in a `def linesToWrite = ...` and it wasn't functional. I don't know what to say else, except "Thank you, Sir!"